# Partial Evaluation of ConstantExpression in ExpressionTreeVisitor

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expression-trees

I am not an Expression Tree master by any stretch of the imagination, what I have is code that looks like this:

```
    int external = 10;
    using(var session = new Session())
    {
       session.Add(new Product { Name = "test1", Price = 20 });
       session.Add(new Product {Name = "test", Price = 10});
       var product = session.Products.Where(p => p.Price == external).FirstOrDefault();
       Assert.Equal(10, product.Price);
    }
```

Session implements all the IQueryProvider, IQueryable interfaces you'd come to expect from a LINQ Provider.

When I evaluate the expression tree, everything goes to plan until I read the ConstantExpression for "external", at which point, I am at a loss as to how to move forward because:

```
      //constant is ConstantExpression for "external" on the right side of the "p.Price == external" expression above.
      var t = constant.GetType(); //evaluates to class called "<>c__DisplayClass2" - with a member named "external" that has the value 10.
```

The question is basically.. How can I just access the value of the member "external" - is there a way to accomplish this without using reflection? or am I cooked? What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your expression captures the `external` local variable, that's why an anonymous type is implicitly created by the compiler to wrap the captured variable. The right-hand side part of the equality is not a `ConstantExpression`, it's actually a `MemberExpression`, whose `Expression` property is a `ConstantExpression` of type `<>c__DisplayClass2`

You can access the value of the property as follows :

```
MemberExpression memberExpr = /* right-hand side of the equality */ as MemberExpression;
ConstantExpression constantExpr = memberExpr.Expression as ConstantExpression;
PropertyInfo prop = memberExpr.Member as PropertyInfo;
object value = prop.GetValue(constantExpr.Value, null);
```

Comment: thanks, I actually discovered something like this on my own a few minutes ago, but it seems that this is actually FieldInfo, not PropertyInfo, thoughts?

Comment: yes, perhaps it's a field... I don't remember exactly how the compiler generates the type to hold the captured locals

Comment: it's a field in your example - but it just as well could be a property on an object - so you'll need both types of reflection sniffing.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer something like this. It is more general and will work for a number of cases.

```
var operation = (BinaryExpression)predicate.Body;
var righthandValue= Expression.Lambda(operation.Right).Compile().DynamicInvoke();
```

Comment: More general, yes, and more terse... but (at this time of writing) compiling an expression tree is a very expensive operation, especially so on x64.

Comment: Btw. this approach is also used in [Matt Warren's MSDN blog post from 1 Aug 2007, "LINQ: Building an IQueryable provider - Part III"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattwar/2007/08/01/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-iii/).